# How do I fix an SQL Database error for a Wordpress Website

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm having this error on my Wordpress website where the customer needs to select sweets to have in a box using checkboxes but the plugin that helped me do that stopped working. Here is the error I got by turning on wp-debug.

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|| NOT FIND_IN_SET( 522 , ywg.products_exclude_id ) )
                        AND ( ywg.visibilit' at line 3 for query SELECT distinct ywt.* FROM HLwygKBByith_wapo_groups ywg join HLwygKBByith_wapo_types ywt on ywg.id=ywt.group_id WHERE
                    ywg.del='0' AND
                    ywt.del='0' AND
                    (
                        ( ( 1=0 AND ( ywg.products_id='' AND ywg.categories_id='' ) ) OR ( FIND_IN_SET( 522 , ywg.products_id ) ) OR ( 1=0 and ( FIND_IN_SET( 36 , ywg.categories_id ) ) ) )
                        AND ( ywg.products_exclude_id='' || ywg.products_exclude_id IS NULL || NOT FIND_IN_SET( 522 , ywg.products_exclude_id ) )
                        AND ( ywg.visibility=9 OR ( ywg.visibility=1 AND 1=1 ) )
                    )
```

Comment: Hey and welcome. Have you done an update of MySQL, PHP version or some plug-ins? It seems that the DB schema is not matching to your (plugin) needs.

Comment: Hey, and thank you! The update of PHP and mySQL is done automatically by the hosting providers I use for the website. The plug in was left untouched, that’s why i was so confused when it suddenly stopped working. I’m pretty sure however I could change the version of php on the panel provided by the hosting guys, not sure about mySQL though.